# Nonnegativity of solution of ODE if $y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

It's known that, if I have positive initial condition and $f(t,0)>0$, so $y(t)$, solution of ODE
$$y'(t)=f(t,y),$$ is nonnegative, because if $T$ is the first time s.t. $y(T)=0$  so $y'(t)>0$ for $t\in (T-\epsilon,T+\epsilon)$, contradiction.

I'd like to know more about the case $f(t,0)=0$. If the initial condition is positive and $f(t,0)=0$, what can I conclude about positiveness?

Thank you so much.

Comment: If $y(t)$ is continuous and $y(0)>0$ then you don't need any other conditions to conclude that $y$ is positive on some interval about $0$. Can you explain your question more?

Comment: @Chrystomath, hi, thank you so much. I'd like to have positiveness all time...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y(t)=0$ is a solution, and if you have the uniqueness property, then no other solution can cross or branch off or in to this solution. Meaning every other solution has one definite sign.

Comment: Really thank you! I did know this (two solution cannot cross) about autonomous ODE's, is it valid for non-autonomous also? Thank you

Comment: If two solutions cross at some point $(t_*,y_*)$, then they solve the same IVP there, thus must be the same, locally and in consequence also globally. So they were not different from the start, or different solutions can not have crossing points.

Comment: Really thank you Lutz Lehmann

Comment: "If the initial condition is positive..." threw me off.

Comment: @Chrystomath, so the solution has the sign of initial condition, positive...?